# Pandas Sum of Duplicate Attributes

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm using Pandas to manipulate a csv file with several rows and columns that looks like the following

```
Fullname     Amount     Date           Zip    State .....
John Joe        1        1/10/1900     55555    Confusion
Betty White     5         .             .       Alaska 
Bruce Wayne     10        .             .       Frustration
John Joe        20        .             .       .
Betty White     25        .             .       .
```

I'd like to create a new column entitled `Total` with a total sum of amount for each person. (Identified by `Fullname` and `Zip`). I'm having difficulty in finding the correct solution.

Let's just call my csv import csvfile. Here is what I have.

```
import Pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('csvfile.csv', header = 0) 
df.sort(['fullname'])
```

I think I have to use the iterrows to do what I want as an object. The problem with dropping duplicates is that I will lose the amount or the amount may be different.

Answer (score 59):

I think you want this:

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby(['Fullname', 'Zip'])['Amount'].transform('sum')
```

So `groupby` will group by the `Fullname` and `zip` columns, as you've stated, we then call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on the `Amount` column and calculate the total amount by passing in the string `sum`, this will return a series with the index aligned to the original `df`, you can then drop the duplicates afterwards. e.g.

```
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Fullname', 'Zip'])
```

Answer (score 11):

Consider using one of following

```py
df = df.groupby(['Fullname', 'Zip'], as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()
df = df.groupby(['Fullname', 'Zip'], as_index=False)['Amount'].cumsum()
df = df.groupby(['Fullname', 'Zip'], as_index=False)['Amount'].agg('sum')
```

All three methods store the result in `Amount` column. Since the meaning of column changes, you could rename the column to another with `df.rename()`

```py
df = df.rename(columns={'Amount':'Total'})
```

If you want to keep one value from other columns, you could use [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), which accepts a dict of axis labels -> functions that specifies what operation should be performed for each column.

```py
df.groupby(['Fullname', 'Zip'], as_index=False).agg({'Amount': 'sum', 'State': 'first'})
```