# Efficiently amalgamate duplicate pixels (by summing) from sparse representation using Python/numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, duplicates

Suppose I have a list of (greyscale) pixels, e.g.

```
x = np.array([13, 14, 14, 14, 15])
y = np.array([ 2,  7,  5,  7,  8])
V = np.array([.3, .7, .4, .2, .1])
```

So, e.g. the second pixel is at location `(14, 7)` with intensity `0.7`

NOTE: `x` is always non-decreasing in this list. So `p > q => x[p] >= x[q]`.

However the same pixel may be revisited. In my example, pixels `#1` and `#3` have coordinates `(14, 7)`.

How to efficiently amalgamate the duplicates?  So that in my example, I get:

```
x2 = np.array([ 13, 14    , 14, 15 ])
y2 = np.array([  2,  7    ,  5,  8 ])
V2 = np.array([ .3, .7+.2 , .4, .1 ])
```

NOTE: Order isn't important, so it may help to sort by increasing `y` for pixels with a given `x`.

NOTE: x, y, V came from cols of a matrix M. What I am to do could be considered as a 2-D histogram or cumulative sum.

IDEA: I could map `x, y -> x + y*nPixelsX`, so now I'm dealing with pairs, e.g. `(1073, 0.4), (1071, 1.8), (1073, 0.7)` which I could sort.

---

EDIT: This is the problem I am actually trying to solve (code is Python despite variable glyphs):

```
# split columns of tradematrix into 1D numpy arrays
time_ms, price, vol, buyer_is_maker = ᬑ.ᘐA.T

# TODO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191535/efficiently-plot-set-of-coordinatevalues-to-numpy-array-bitmap

# convert time,price to pixel x,y coords
x = pX(time_ms)
y = pY(price)

brightness = vol
rgb_channel = np.where(buyer_is_maker, 2, 1)  # cv2 uses BGR not RGB

# make a clear canvas
f = np.zeros((ᬑ.pixelsY, ᬑ.pixelsX, 3))

# additively plot trades
for i in range(len(ᬑ.ᘐA)):
    try:
        f[y[i],x[i],rgb_channel[i]] += brightness[i]
    except:
        # don't plot offscreen coords
        # try/catch is waaay faster than doing if on_screen(x[i],y[i]):
        pass

# flatten dynamic range (as some trades are huge)
# ... by doing `w -> log(1+w)` 3 times

# # This was the original (slow) code
# for _ in range(3):
#     f = np.log(1+f)  # any 0 pixel maps back to 0 (log 1 = 0)

# sped up!
sparse_red = coo_matrix(f[:,:,2])
sparse_green = coo_matrix(f[:,:,1])
for _ in range(3):
    np.log(1+sparse_red.data, sparse_red.data)  # perform operation in place
    np.log(1+sparse_green.data, sparse_green.data)  # perform operation in place
f[:,:,2] = sparse_red.todense()
f[:,:,1] = sparse_green.todense()

# normalize canvas
sup = np.max(f)
if sup > 0:
    f /= sup
```

What I'm doing isn't great. I'm writing sparse data to a bitmap so as to solve this "multiple trades on the same pixel" problem, then sparsifying the bitmap to flatten the trades, then recombining.

I need to be working with sparse data all the way to the end, I think.

Comment: What is the exact type of `pix`? (including his shape if this is a numpy ndarray)

Comment: @JérômeRichard I've updated the question

Comment: missing APL tag!

Comment: It's Python actually !

Comment: Consider looking `np.log1p`

Comment: Saw your prior question. Since this is really a bitmap, I've updated my answer with a one-liner

Comment: @MadPhysicist Super-helpful, both the answer and the update. 
If only I could find an engineer of your calibre outside of SO... I am entering a phase of heavy numerical analysis. Please feel most welcome to connect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by sorting the arrays using [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
i = np.lexsort([y, x])  # [0, 2, 1, 3, 4]
y = y[i]                # [2, 5, 7, 7, 8]
x = x[i]                # [13, 14, 14, 14, 15]
V = V[i]                # [0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1]
```

It's fairly easy to identify duplicates among the coordinates using [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html):

```
mask = (np.diff(x) == 0) & (np.diff(y) == 0)
same = np.flatnonzero(mask)  # [2]
```

The problem is that this does not make it easy to process the case where you have multiple duplicate of the same pixel. I propose instead that you generate an index of all the non-duplicates, with some small modifications:

```
diff = np.r_[0, 1 + np.flatnonzero(~mask)]
```

The really neat thing is that all duplicates, even multiple visits will be simply missing from `diff`. That means that you can pass it directly to [`np.add.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html):

```
V = np.add.reduceat(V, diff)
```

You can delete duplicate coordinates using [`np.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
x = np.delete(x, same)
y = np.delete(y, same)
```

If you care about the original sort order, you can use the fact that [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is its own inverse. That means that to return the arrays to original order, you need to delete `same + 1` from `i` and argsort it to reinstate the order:

```
i = np.delete(i, same + 1).argsort()
x = x[i]
y = y[i]
V = V[i]
```

Keep in mind that when we deleted `same` from `x` and `y`, we were keeping the last duplicated element. To preserve the order, you likely want to keep the first element, hence `same + 1`.

---

If you are OK with simply reconstructing an image, the task becomes infinitely simpler, since you can use [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) to accumulate the pixels directly in an unbuffered manner:

```
nPixelsY = 16
nPixelsX = 16
img = np.zeros((nPixelsY, nPixelsX))
np.add.at(img, (y, x), V)
```

And indeed you can see that

```
>>> img[7, 14]
0.8999999999999999
```

Contrast with `img[y, x] += V`, which is buffered, and will therefore discard duplicates.

Comment: Would it condense the solution path to map `(x,y) -> x + y * nPixelsX`?  Then I'm dealing with (pixelIndex, val)  pairs...

Comment: @Pi. That would work. It wouldn't make a huge difference because you're only doing one sort. It might save you some time, but probably not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to develop a purely numpy way of doing this however I am not currently successful, however I am able to come up with one using pandas if that is acceptable:

```
bitmap = np.zeros((15, 16))

## generate data 
s_x = np.array([a for a in range(-5,18)], dtype=int)
s_x = np.repeat(s_x, 2)
s_y = np.array([a for a in range(-3,20)], dtype=int)
s_y = np.repeat(s_y, 2)

np.random.shuffle(s_x)
np.random.shuffle(s_y)

## make sure there are some repeats 
s_x = np.concatenate((s_x, s_x[:5]))
s_y = np.concatenate((s_y, s_y[:5]))

pixel_count = s_x.shape[0]
pixel_val = np.random.rand(pixel_count)

# ## generate is done 

start = time.time()

## create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'s_x':s_x, 's_y':s_y, 'pixel_val': pixel_val})

## remove pixels outside the image
df = df[(s_x >= 0)*(s_x < bitmap.shape[1])*(s_y >= 0)*(s_y < bitmap.shape[0])]

## sum duplicate pixels 
pixel_val = df.groupby(['s_x', 's_y'])['pixel_val'].transform('sum')

## get the index of the unique pixel locations 
use = pixel_val.index

bitmap[s_y[use], s_x[use]] = pixel_val

end = time.time()

print(end- start)

plt.imshow(bitmap)
```

source: [Pandas Sum of Duplicate Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583312/pandas-sum-of-duplicate-attributes)

output:

[image]