# Efficiently plot set of {coordinate+value}s to (numpy array) bitmap

Tags: arrays, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have a set of pixel values, e.g.

```py
> S[42]
6, 2, (0.1, 0, 0)
```

^ here the 42nd entry is for pixel location `(6,2)` with a dull red color.

How to efficiently plot `S` into a fresh numpy bitmap array `bitmap = np.zeros((1024, 768, 3))`?

Is there some vectorized solution (rather than a `for` loop)?

I can split `S` by columns into `S_x`, `S_y` and `S_RGB` if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how you do it, yes splitting up is helpful, and use the same datatypes I have below

```
bitmap = np.zeros((10, 10, 3))
    
s_x = (1,2,3) ## tuple
s_y = (0,1,2) ## tuple
pixal_val = np.array([[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]) ## np

bitmap[s_y, s_x] = pixal_val

plt.imshow(bitmap)
```

output:

[image]

**Edit:**

it does work with using numpy arrays as coordinates but make sure they are type int

```
bitmap = np.zeros((10, 10, 3))

s_x = np.array([a for a in range(10)], dtype=int)
s_y = np.array([a for a in range(10)], dtype=int)
    
np.random.shuffle(s_x)
np.random.shuffle(s_y)

pixel_val = np.random.rand(10,3)

bitmap[s_y, s_x] = pixel_val

plt.imshow(bitmap)
```

[image]

**final edit:** s_x ans s_y where the wrong way round I have fixed above

Comment: Such a beautiful answer.  I'm now running into trouble with offscreen coords.  I've asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206205/efficiently-plot-coordinate-set-to-numpy-bitmap-array-excluding-offscreen-coor