# Efficiently plot coordinate set to numpy (bitmap) array excluding offscreen coordinates

Tags: numpy, bitmap, coordinates, vectorization

This question follows from [Efficiently plot set of {coordinate+value}s to (numpy array) bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191535/efficiently-plot-set-of-coordinatevalues-to-numpy-array-bitmap)

A solution for plotting from x, y, color lists to a bitmap is given:

```
bitmap = np.zeros((10, 10, 3))

s_x = (0,1,2) ## tuple
s_y = (1,2,3) ## tuple
pixal_val = np.array([[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]) ## np

bitmap[s_x, s_y] = pixal_val

plt.imshow(bitmap)
```

But how to handle the case where some (x,y) pairs lie outside the bitmap?

Efficiency is paramount.

If I could map offscreen coords to the first row/col of the bitmap `(-42, 7) -> (0, 7)`, `(15, -6) -> (15, 0)`, I could simply black out the first row&col with `bitmap[:,0,:] = 0; bitmap[0,:,:] = 0`.

Is this doable?

Is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting offscreen coords? if so don't worry otherwise I was just wondering if it was using a non-traditional coordinate system - where the zero may be in the center of the image for whatever reason

Anyway, after my revelation that you can use numpy arrays to store the coordinates, mapping outliers to the first row/col is pretty straightforward, simply using: `s_x[s_x < 0] = 0`, however, i believe the most efficient way to use logic to find the index of the pixels you want to use so only they are allocated - see below:

```
bitmap = np.zeros((15, 16, 3))

## generate data 
s_x = np.array([a for a in range(-3,22)], dtype=int)
s_y = np.array([a for a in range(-4,21)], dtype=int)

np.random.shuffle(s_x)
np.random.shuffle(s_y)

print(s_x)
print(s_y)

pixel_val = np.random.rand(25,3)
## generate is done 

use = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(s_x >= 0, s_x < bitmap.shape[1]), np.logical_and(s_y >= 0, s_y < bitmap.shape[0]))

bitmap[s_y[use], s_x[use]] = pixel_val[use]
    
plt.imshow(bitmap)
```

output:

coordinates:

```
[ 8  3 21  9 -2 -3  5 14 -1 18 13 16  0 11  7  1  2 12 15  6 19 10  4 17 20]
[ 8 14  1  9  2  4  7 15  3 -3 19 16  6 -1  0 17  5 13 -2 20 -4 11 10 12 18]
```

image:

[image]

I ran a test where it had to allocate 3145728 (four times the size of the bitmap you gave in your other question), around half of which were outside the image and on average it took around 140ms, whereas remapping the outliers and then setting the first row/col to zero took 200ms for the same task

Comment: Such clean examples.  The work of a scientist I suspect. May I push my luck once more? The final problem I need to solve is dealing with duplicate pixels: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191456/efficiently-amalgamate-duplicates-by-summing-over-list-of-greyscale-pixels-u ... can you see a path through?

Comment: You can replace `logical_and` with just `&` operator. Looks much neater.

Comment: yeah, I dropped it altogether for '*' later