# Pandas: How to get Unique combinations of two column values in either ways?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I would like to know how we can get the unique combination of two column values if the values are in a similar combination. Below is the dataframe

[image]

I tried using below code but my expected output is different

df.groupby(['column1', 'column2'], as_index = False).agg({'expense' : 'sum'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583312/pandas-sum-of-duplicate-attributes), but an important distinction is that it seems you don't care about the order of `column1` or `column2`. Before I share the solution, here's the pseudocode:

1. Create an `id` column which we can use to find rows where the sets of `column1` and `column2` are the same
2. Apply the approach from the linked post to `id`.
3. Drop duplicates based on id

Here's my manual transcription of the data. In the future, please provide the sample data as text, instead of as a screenshot.

```
column1,column2,salary
ram,shyam,100
sita,geeta,500
geeta,sita,300
shyam,ram,600
sohan,mohan,200
mohan,sohan,400
```

And here's the code

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
>>> hash_func = lambda n: hash("-".join(sorted(n)))
>>> df['id'] = df[['column1','column2']].apply(hash_func, axis=1)
>>> df
  column1 column2  salary                   id
0     ram   shyam     100 -1387604912582040812
1    sita   geeta     500  9030593041392264307
2   geeta    sita     300  9030593041392264307
3   shyam     ram     600 -1387604912582040812
4   sohan   mohan     200  6327789560655124249
5   mohan   sohan     400  6327789560655124249
>>> df['expense'] = df.groupby('id')['salary'].transform('sum')
>>> df
   column1 column2  salary                   id  expense
0     ram   shyam     100  7227562739062788100      700
1    sita   geeta     500  6328366926112663723      800
2   geeta    sita     300  6328366926112663723      800
3   shyam     ram     600  7227562739062788100      700
4   sohan   mohan     200 -3239226935758438599      600
5   mohan   sohan     400 -3239226935758438599      600
>>> df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'])
>>> df
  column1 column2  salary                   id  expense
0     ram   shyam     100  7227562739062788100      700
1    sita   geeta     500  6328366926112663723      800
4   sohan   mohan     200 -3239226935758438599      600
>>> df = df.drop(columns=['id','salary']) # some extra cleanup
>>> df 
  column1 column2  expense
0     ram   shyam      700
1    sita   geeta      800
4   sohan   mohan      600
```

Comment: EDIT: changed hash function using improvements provided by @Rajarshi Ghosh

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed solution. The hash function is an eye-opener. Your solution is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps

```
df['pairs'] = df['col1'] + '-' + df['col2']
```

Then apply a `foo` function to this column
The idea of this function is to take the `pairs` column data and sort it based on the 1st character of each element in the pair.

for example input is `ram-shyam` or `ram-shaym` we will get output as `ram-shyam`

This is the `foo` function -

```
def foo(s):
    lst_s = s.split('-')
    temp = {}
    for idx, name in enumerate(lst_s):
        temp[idx]= name[0]

    temp = dict(sorted(temp.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
    
    final = []
    for key in temp.keys():
        final.append(lst_s[key])
    return '-'.join(final)
```

Now apply this function on the `pairs` column

```
df['unique-pair'] = df['pairs'].apply(foo)
```

The output looks now like this -

```
col1    col2    salary  unique-pair     pairs
0   ram     shyam   100     ram-shyam   ram-shyam
1   sita    gita    500     gita-sita   sita-gita
2   gita    sita    300     gita-sita   gita-sita
3   shyam   ram     600     ram-shyam   shyam-ram
4   sohan   mohan   200     mohan-sohan     sohan-mohan
5   mohan   sohan   400     mohan-sohan     mohan-sohan
```

Now you can do a group by

```
df.groupby(['unique-pair']).agg({'salary':sum})
```

final output is -

```
salary
unique-pair     
gita-sita   800
mohan-sohan     600
ram-shyam   700
```

Comment: You could simplify the `foo` function entirely to something like: ```python
df['unique-pair'] = df[['column1','column2']].apply(lambda n: "-".join(sorted(n)),axis=1)```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This method is also great to handle pairing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the first and second columns so that `a,b` and `b,a` are treated as the same in groupby.

Now, since the `sort()` is deprecated, we can use numpy sort and re-create a new dataframe.

Assuming the following [csv_file](https://github.com/abcnishant007/congestion-and-grid-overload/files/8395077/csvfile.csv):

```
 column1,column2,salary
    a,b,1
    c,b,3
    b,a,10
    b,c,30
    d,e,99
```

We can do it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("csvfile.csv",)
print("Original:\n ",df.head())

print ("\nGrouped sum:\n")
print ((pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[df.columns[:2]], axis=1), columns=df.columns[:2]),\
                   df["salary"]], axis=1)).reset_index(drop=True, inplace=False).groupby\
                   (["column1", "column2"]).sum())
```

The output is shown below:

```
Original:
    column1 column2  salary
0       a       b       1
1       c       b       3
2       b       a      10
3       b       c      30
4       d       e      99

Grouped sum:

                 salary
column1 column2        
a       b            11
b       c            33
d       e            99
```